# How do I access the JQuery DataTables plugin aoData values in MVC3?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datatables

I am using MVC 3. How do I access the data sent by fnServerParams in an aoData object on the controller? Thanks

UPDATE: This is the jquery I am trying to use...

```
 function GenerateRows()
 {
 var serverParams = { "invoiceDate": "", "contractID": "" }

 serverParams.invoiceDate = $( "#InvoiceDate" ).val();
 serverParams.contractID = $( "#ContractID" ).val();

 $( '#invoiceRows' ).dataTable( {

    // Table style
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bSort": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bServersSide": true,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "oTableTools": {
        "aButtons": [],
        "sRowSelect": "single"
    },
    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',

    // Server Parameters
    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData )
    {
        aoData.push( { "name": "invoiceDate", "value": "2012-10-10" } )
    },

    // Aajax Call
    "sAjaxSource": "/Invoice/GetDailyRateBillingRows",
    "bProcessing": false,
    "bRetrieve": true,
    "aoColumns": [
                    { "sName": "Detail" },
                    { "sName": "Qty" },
                    { "sName": "Price" },
                    { "sName": "RowTotal" }
                ]
} );
}
```

Action Method : needs to receive the invoice date and contract id

```
// Method to return InvoiceRows for DailyRate billing        
    public ActionResult GetDailyRateBillingRows(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
    {
        // Hard coded. Need to receive parameters from Ajax post. (DataTables request.)
        DateTime invoiceDate = new DateTime(2012, 12, 31);
        int contractID = 1;


        int contractDayRate = db.Contracts.Where(c => c.Id == contractID).First().UnitRate;

        List<InvoiceRow> invoiceRows = new List<InvoiceRow>();

        List<DateTime> businessDaysOfMonth = new List<DateTime>();

        var firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(invoiceDate.Year, invoiceDate.Month, 1);
        var lastDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);

        var holidays = db.Holidays.Where(h => h.DateOfHoliday >= firstDayOfMonth && h.DateOfHoliday <= lastDayOfMonth);

        // Get all the week days into businessDaysOfMonth
        for (DateTime date = firstDayOfMonth; date <= lastDayOfMonth; date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            if (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                businessDaysOfMonth.Add(date);
        }

        // Now remove the matching public holidays.
        foreach (var item in holidays)
        {
            businessDaysOfMonth.Remove(item.DateOfHoliday);
        }

        // .. and create list of invoiceRow items.
        foreach (var item in businessDaysOfMonth)
        {
            invoiceRows.Add(new InvoiceRow { InvoiceID = 0, ItemPrice = contractDayRate, RowDetail = GetDateString(item), RowQty = 1, RowTotal = contractDayRate });
        }

        var result = from c in invoiceRows
                     select new[] { c.RowDetail, c.RowQty.ToString(), c.ItemPrice.ToString(), c.RowTotal.ToString() };

        return Json(new { eEcho = param.sEcho, iTotalRecords = invoiceRows.Count(), iTotalDisplayRecords = invoiceRows.Count(), aaData = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    private string GetDateString(DateTime date)
    {
        return date.ToString("dddd dd MMM yyyy");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201849/whats-the-correct-ajax-pattern-for-using-the-jquery-datatable-with-asp-net-mvc/4221720#4221720

Comment: Question above is more of a design pattern question. My question is asking how one accesses aoData on the controller

Comment: You cannot access aoData on the controller, you can only pass it from your jQuery code to the controller, for instance by means of an Ajax call.

Comment: I am trying to pass parameters to the controller that will be used to build data for the response. As an example I am using the following code:// Server Parameters
        "fnServerParams": function ( aoData )
        {
            aoData.push( { "name": "invoiceDate", "value": "2012-10-10" } )
        },  .... Is this approach wrong? If so, how can I send additional data to the server?

Comment: The application is for generating invoices. I need to send a invoice date (and a ContractID) to the controller Action method. The ActionMethod then builds an array of billable days in the months and sends the array back to the Datatables which binds the Json array.

Comment: OK - I found it in the Request.QueryString because its a GET! Doh, shoulda looked there first.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, please notice `fnServerParams` is new since version 1.8.2, so please make sure you are running the latest release of dataTables.

You should be able to get it like this in your Controller method (`GetDailyRateBillingRows`):

```
var invoiceDate = HttpContext.Request["invoiceDate"];
```