# JQuery Datatables and ASP.NET MVC Parameter to ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm trying to return a View with a Jquery datatable, whose action is launched from a previous page with the ActionLink--

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Audit", "Audit", new { id= Model.ID })
```

The Jquery datatable is then pre-filtered with the ID passed from the Model ID.

Here is my JS file...(incidentally, a static value e.g. 10005 works here in the fnServerParams, but I need the value to be dynamic based on whatever Model ID is chosen from theprevious screen)

```
var oTable = $('#myAuditTable').dataTable({
     "sAjaxSource": "GetAuditLog",
        "fnServerParams": function ( aoData )
    {            aoData.push({ "name": "ID", "value": 10005 })
     },
 "aoColumns": [
....
```

Here is my Audit.cshtml page.

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.AuditLog>

<table id="myAuditTable" width="100%">
                <tr>...</tr>
</table>
```

and in the Controller

```
    public ActionResult GetAuditLog(int ID){

        var logs = db.AuditLog.Where(c => c.ID == ID).ToList();

        var result = from c in logs
                     select new[] { ....
                     };

        return Json(new
        {
            aaData = result
        }, "text/x-json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

So I normally would pass a parameter in MVC like so:

```
    public ActionResult Audit(int ID)
    {            
        return View(); 
    }
```

But since the GetAuditLog is the action getting results, how do I get the int ID to the GetAuditLog action in order to pass the filter the records, which in turn get passed as JSON. I can't call GetAuditLog in the ActionLink, because its job is to pull JSON, not render a View.

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I've gone through this guy's articles cause they are pretty comprehensive as far as integrating ASP.NET and datatables.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part
But cannot find an exact fit to my problem.
This post seems to come close...
[How do I access the JQuery DataTables plugin aoData values in MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505639/how-do-i-access-the-jquery-datatables-plugin-aodata-values-in-mvc3)
But doesn't quite apply since he seems to be working with a successfully passed-in parameter.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can achieve this by two ways:

First create a **hidden field having value from Model.Id** and then assign this hidden field value to your datatable() function in like this

in view:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ID" value="@Model.ID" name="ID" />
```

and then put your below peace of code under **document.ready** and assign value ID from hidden field like this :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var oTable = $('#myAuditTable').dataTable({
   "sAjaxSource": "GetAuditLog",
    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData )
    {            aoData.push({ "name": "ID", "value": $("#ID").val() })
    },
     "aoColumns": [
    ....

    });
```

Second: Put your datatable() function in your view under script tag and assign Model.Id directly like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var oTable = $('#myAuditTable').dataTable({
 "sAjaxSource": "GetAuditLog",
    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData )
{            aoData.push({ "name": "ID", "value": '@Model.ID' })
 },
     "aoColumns": [
    ....
    </script>
```

Hope this will resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is getting the Model.ID value into the hidden field from the previous page's action link. Because the Audit.cshtml View is using another model from GetAuditLog, which is dependent on the Model.ID passed from previous page. The only way I can think is to do some kind of Partial View, but not sure how that would work.